# Magnolia grandiflora: How is flowering affected in case of propagation by layering?

Tags: propagation, flowering, magnolia

I've got a 10 year old *Magnolia grandiflora* that flowered last year for the first time.

If I manage to propagate it by layering, would the new plant have flowers the first year after separating from the mother plant? Or would I have to wait certain number of years again? In such case, would I have to wait another 10 years, or perhaps 2-3 years?

Is ability to flower affected by the age of the plant's "branch material" only, or perhaps also by size of roots, age of roots, etc.?

Comment: I would purchase already cultivated plants from the nursery  Take a picture of your tree and explain how you see cloning this tree to make another (give it 5 years for a successful clone to get 5 feet in height).

Answer (score 3):

I have several *Magnolia grandifloras*, planted about 21 years ago. It took 12 years or so to bloom. Most blooms are pretty high in the trees (we are sort of in a jungle), so  I planted some dwarf hybrid (don't know the variety) and it bloomed the second year, at about 8 feet tall. The blooms are not quite the giants of the Southern Magnolia but are much easier to pick. So, if you want blooms in less than 10 years, I think you should think hybrid. I never grew any from cuttings.